# How to change terminal background to photo in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, background-image, osascript

In order to help differentiate between terminal windows from a 30k foot view, I'd like to have different background pics for my terminal windows.

Every time a terminal window opens, I'd like to set the background to a random pic from a certain folder.

I know you can change the color via osascript stuff, but I haven't seen how I could set a current terminal's background to a pic (and not change the background for all of them).

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Wrong site. This site is for programming related questions. For this question, you're looking for a different site such as [apple.se] or [su]. The [help] has more details regarding the types of question that are appropriate here.

Comment: K.  I'll repost to Ask Different.  Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless something has changed, OS X does not expose the background image property to osascript.

However, you can do the following:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set background color of first window to {0,17655,0,-16373}'
```

So, you could change the color via script.  If you really want an image, though, when you go into the terminal preferences, rather than choosing a single image choose a folder containing a set of images.  If you do this, each terminal will successively iterate through these background images!